# Is it possible to highlight x and y axes on Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have created a scatter chart with Highcharts, both x and y axes range is from -20 to 20. It is shown as a grid, I set "gridLineWidth: 1" both for x and y, so all the lines have the same width.

Is it possible to give a different width only to x and y axes which cross the origin?

Comment: You only want the origin to be thicker? You can use `renderer` to overlap that intersection if you want.

Comment: Try posting a jsfiddle of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/gamc4whf/

Comment: Could you attach a mockup of your goal?

Comment: Sure, here is an image.
https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/500x494q90/905/zCuA07.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I've solved using plotLines to both axes.